# Add Office 365 users to AD in VM in Azure

Tags: sharepoint, azure, active-directory

we have a vm in azure with AD + a SharePoint 2013 that joined that domain.
We have also an Office 365 account with a domain. This domain is added to the Active Directory in Azure.
Now we can see all of our 30 office 365 users in Azure.

Now we need to sync this office 365 users to the VM in azure that runs the AD.
We need a single sign on solution that our office 365 users can log on with there office 365 credentials to the SharePoint 2013 Server.

Is this possible? When Yes, how?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the Directory Integration feature of Windows Azure AD.  From the Azure Portal, enable Directory Integration for your directory and then download the Directory Sync tool.  This will enable you to sync between your Azure AD Tenant and your Server AD running in your Virtual Machine.

[image: Directory Integration]

It's recommended you configure a separate Directory Sync Server to install the tool on.  But, it's also possible to just run it on your Server AD Virtual Machine.  I've done it both ways successfully.

When you're installing the tool, select the option for Hybrid Deployment.  This will enable Azure AD to write objects back to your Server AD.

[image: Hybrid Deployment]

Comment: but you talking about this sync:

AD --> Azure AD (Office 365)

what I need is

Azure AD (Office 365) --> AD

Regards!

Comment: That is what the Hybrid Deployment feature is for.